# How to add jqplot to custom Joomla (3.3) component?

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, jqplot

Before I started with Joomla I developed a html page that uses jqplot, and that pages worked/works fine.

Now I want to include jqplot in a custom joomla (3.3) component that I'm developing, but when calling the component (by means of main menu item) no chart is shown.

UPDATE DEFAULT.PHP (JOOMLA) CODE FURTHER TO COMMENT:

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
$document = JFactory::getDocument();

//add jqplot libraries
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
$document->addScript(JPATH_ROOT.'/media/system/js/jquery.jqplot.min.js');
$document->addStyleSheet(JPATH_ROOT.'/media/system/js/jquery.jqplot.min.css');
$document->addScript(JPATH_ROOT.'/media/system/js/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js');
$document->addScript(JPATH_ROOT.'/media/system/js/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js');
$document->addScript(JPATH_ROOT.'/media/system/js/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js');
$document->addScript(JPATH_ROOT.'/media/system/js/jqplot.enhancedLegendRenderer.js');
$document->addScript(JPATH_ROOT.'/media/system/js/weqlib.js');

?>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]); //copied from example at http://www.jqplot.com/tests/line-charts.php

    }); //$(document).ready
</script>
</head>

<!--<h1><?php echo $this->msg; ?></h1>-->
<h1>Prosumer Dashboard </h1>

<div id="chart1" style="width:600px; height:250px;"> </div>
```

I think the way I call the libabries is wrong (I know for sure the jqplot function call is ok, as I also copied this from my old html file).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should add javascript to the head of the page in the following way...

```
<?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript('/media/system/js/sample.js');
?>
```

Your script currently will be attempting to load the javascript in relation to the page's URL, not in relation to your component's URL, so it will not be finding them.

Also, Joomla 3 comes with JQuery - load it like this (possibly in your template rather than your component)...

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

Note that this runs in no conflict mode, so you have to replace any '$' in your jquery scripts with the 'jQuery'.   You can also make it run in conflict mode...

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework', false);
```

However, this may cause problems if your site has any other libraries running.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, Richard. Further to your suggestion I changed the code of the default.php file, but the front page is not showing any graph. Also, the console displays a number of 404 errors telling it cannot find the jqplot js files, which I don't understand at all, as the paths in the console match the paths of the files??? Note that I included the JPATH_ROOT; without that constant the console alsow showed 404 errors plus the wrong path. I run Joomla on my laptop (localhost)